# The below code is taking very long to execute in jupyter notebook. Why?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, nltk, python-re

The below code is taking an eternity to run in jupyter notebook. Why is it happening?
I waa trying to remove the exclamation marks and articles from the customer reviews as a part of data preprocessing.

````
import pandas as pd
import re
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.stem.porter import PorterStemmer

df = pd.read_csv('balanced_reviews.csv')
ps = PorterStemmer()
corpus = []
for i in range(0,527332):
    review = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]', ' ', df.iloc[i,1])
    
    review = review.lower()
    
    review = review.split()
    
    #stopwords removal
    review = [word for word in review if word not in stopwords.words('english')]
    
    #steming
    review = [ps.stem(word) for word in review]
    
    review = " ".join(review)
    corpus.append(review)```
````

Comment: What is `stopwords.words`? What is `df`?

Comment: Did you try to profile the code? Please read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/. How long do you expect it to take to process one cell from the DataFrame? How many cells do you expect will be processed? If you multiply that out, is the actual time taken surprising?

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, 527,332 rows is quite a few rows. You can expect it to take a while. But one thing that jumps out is the way you use the nltk's `stopwords`. This returns a list, read from a disk file. Even if the disk file is not read in again every time you reference it (I have not checked), searching in a list is sloooooow. Load the stopwords into a *set* above your for-loop, and you can filter them quickly without reloading anything.

```
en_stopwords = set(stopwords.words('english'))
for i in ...
    ...
    review = [word for word in review if word not in en_stopwords]
```

Finally, using `append` on a list in a long loop is inefficient, because Python has to keep growing the array. Wrap the processing of `review` in function and use a list comprehension (instead of the for-loop) to collect the values:

```
en_stopwords = set(stopwords.words('english'))
corpus = [ cleanup(df.iloc[i,1]) for i in range(527332) ]
```

Or, since you happen to know the length of your dataframe, pre-allocate a list of the same length and filled with None, and replace them with the reviews. Both methods should be much faster than repeated appending.

Once you've done these obvious things, if performance is still inconveniently slow it's time to profile your code, and see what else might be holding it up.